# python | accessing field of a namedtuple created from <'bs4.element.ResultSet'>

Tags: python

So first, the code is as follows:

```
from web_api import search_things  # web_api is a python file within the module and uses an api and bs4 to fetch data
from collections import namedtuple

things_dict = search_things(keyword="piano")  # search_things() is a method from web_api, again uses bs4 to fetch data from API
[*thing_list] = things_dict  # stores API response in a list
thing_structure = namedtuple('thing', ['id', 'title', 'price'])


def get_thing(things):
    final_list = []
    for i, j in enumerate(things):
        [list_id] = things[i].itemid  # '.itemid' refers to the specific data in things_dict ... and things_dict is of class <bs4.element.ResultSet>
        [list_title] = things[i].title 
        [list_price] = things[i].currentprice
        things_tuple = [
              thing_structure(list_id, list_title, list_price)
        ]
        final_list.append(things_tuple)
    return final_list


search_things = get_things(thing_list)  # this line works as intended! returns all data's in their respective fields within the namedtuple structure. BUT!

for i, j in enumerate(search_things):
    thing_price = search_things[i].price  # the '.price' field name declared within the namedtuple is highlighted as an unresolved reference!
    print(thing_price)  # output is : AttributeError 'list' object has no attribute 'price'
```

so i'm trying to access each field's within the namedtuple seperately but some reason python won't let me

Comment: What is the output of `type(search_things)`? and what does`search_things` contains? Can you show sample data we can work with?

Comment: Solved now! but to answer your question, it was giving me as type 'list' which was expected. However, notice the variable things_tuple is not surrounded in brackets as [things_tuple]. This mistake stopped me from being able to give an index for each set of tuple in the list. So instead of having index 0 for every tuple, post-change I could actually index a tuple at index[1] or [99] etc. As always thanks!